# Why am I not able to get the cursor in search field inside the dropdown?

Tags: reactjs

I need a search box inside the dropdown. I have inserted the search box but unable to type anything as there is no cursor appearing on click. Not sure whether it's because of overlapping. How can I proceed with this problem?

I created two search box-one inside the dropdown and the other outside just to see how the search actually works. The one outside allows me to type whereas the other won't.

Given below is the code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DpDwn from "./dropdown.json";
import "./App.css";
import "./carbon-components-stylesheet.css";
import {
  DropdownV2,
  Search,
  Accordion,
  AccordionItem
} from "carbon-components-react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedItem: "Label",
      selectedId: 0
    };
  }

  render() {
    const onChange = search_item => {
      console.log(search_item.target.value);
    };
    const itemToElement = item => {
      return (
        <li
          style={{ height: 20 }}
          value={item.value}
          onClick={evt => {
            evt.preventDefault();
          }}
          onKeyPress={evt => evt.preventDefault()}
          tabIndex={-1}
          id="listUsed"
        >
          <Search
            className="some-class"
            name="abc"
            defaultValue=""
            labelText="Search"
            closeButtonLabelText=""
            placeHolderText="Search"
            onChange={onChange}
            onClick={event => {
              console.log("hi");
            }}
            id="search-2"
          />
          <Accordion>
            {item.lvl_1.map((item0, index) => {
              return (
                <AccordionItem title={item0.BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME} id="lvl1">
                  {item0.lvl_2.map((item1, index) => {
                    return (
                      <AccordionItem title={item1.BRAND_NAME} id="lvl2">
                        {item1.lvl_3.map((item2, index) => {
                          return (
                            <p
                              onClick={() => {
                                ReactDOM.findDOMNode(
                                  this
                                ).getElementsByClassName(
                                  "bx--list-box__menu"
                                )[0].style.display = "none";

                                ReactDOM.findDOMNode(
                                  this
                                ).getElementsByClassName(
                                  "bx--list-box__menu-icon bx--list-box__menu-icon--open"
                                )[0].className = "bx--list-box__menu-icon";

                                this.setState({
                                  selectedItem: item2.NAME,
                                  selectedId: item2.VALUE
                                });
                              }}
                            >
                              {item2.NAME}
                            </p>
                          );
                        })}
                      </AccordionItem>
                    );
                  })}
                </AccordionItem>
              );
            })}
          </Accordion>
        </li>
      );
    };
    const items4dropDown = DpDwn.map(item => ({
      lvl_1: item.lvl_1
    }));

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div style={{ width: 300, position: "relative", top: "100px" }}>
          <Search
            className="some-class"
            name="abc"
            defaultValue=""
            labelText="Search"
            closeButtonLabelText=""
            placeHolderText="Search"
            onChange={onChange}
            onClick={event => {
              console.log("hi");
            }}
            id="search-1"
          />
          <DropdownV2
            label={this.state.selectedItem}
            ariaLabel="Dropdown"
            items={items4dropDown}
            itemToElement={itemToElement}
            onClick={evt => {
              evt.preventDefault();
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I need the search box inside the dropdown to show the cursor so that it allows input of text

Comment: Please don't use `getElementsByClassName` like this - it's a mess and disagrees with React's usage. 
We also need more info about components that you just used.

Comment: I have used only 4 carbon-components and added some styling. Can you please tell me what more information do you need

Comment: Also I'm new to react so have no much idea about usage of `getElementsByClassName` so can you please suggest me the correct way of using it?